# Parse jtring date with objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c++

i have a NSString variables like this 
dd-MM-YYYY exemple 30-05-2011 . How can i get day in a variable , month in variable and year in variable ?
thank you

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380381/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-objective-c

Comment: @Jason @cs thank you but i can't just do it with Regular expression or sbstring ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`NSDateComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

In particular, for the format "dd-MM-YYYY":

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd'-'MM'-'yyyy"];
// Your date represented as a NSDate
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:myDateString];
// Now, use NSCalendar / NSDateComponents to get the components
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                          fromDate:date];
```

Now you're free to access `[comps day]`, `[comps month]`, and `[comps year]`.

See [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for a description of all the format-parsing options. Keep in mind that NSDateFormatter also supports older versions of this standard, so you'll have to be careful.

Comment: thank you but i have an EXC bad access when i trie it.daparatureFly.date is a string , it's not a problem ? . this is the code    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd'-'MM'-'yyyy"];
    
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:daparatureFly.date];
    
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                              fromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"year : %@",[comps year]);

Comment: You can't use `%@` when displaying a number. `[comps year]` will be a `NSInteger`, so you should use `%d` or `%ld`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something along the lines of ...

```
    NSString *dateAsString = @"30-05-2011";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"d-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *datePlain = [formatter dateFromString:dateAsString]; 
    [formatter release];
```

and then use the NSDate object datePlain

Comment: thank you but then how i will take them separetly with datePlain ?

Comment: @Mehdi Maybe I should have explicitly specified that you could use NSCalendar in conjunction with the NSDate object. I see that @jtbandes has answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `dateFromString:` method of `NSDateFormatter`.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *d = [df dateFromString:@"2011-05-10"];
[df release];
```

You can do whatever you need to do with the `NSDate` object.