# How to check NSString to date

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

How can I check NSString is date or not?
For example:

NSString - `Jul 14 at 14.55 PM` return `TRUE`

NSString - `Talala...` return `False`

Please help..

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380381/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-objective-c/4380393#4380393) answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're on iOS you can check that using [NSDataDetector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009936)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `NSDateFormatter` and allow it to use an heuristic to determine if the given input string is a date or not (just call `[formatter setLeninent:YES]` for this).
If it can create a `NSDate` object out of your `NSString`, congratulations, the string contains a date, otherwise it most likely doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a new `NSDate` instance giving the `NSString` and check wether the result is `nil` or not.

[NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: That will only work if the date is in a specific format sadly.