# Convert string date format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

I have date in string in this formate **"Tue, 23 Oct 2012 01:05:00 +0000"**. Now i want to convert date format to "**TUE OCT 23 2012  1:05AM**". What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How are you proposing to get from 1:05am to 2:25pm, and from October 23rd to October 19th?

Comment: i just mention formats as a requirements. These dates are not equal to each other

Comment: Then that's a really poor way of writing the question. *Every* question I've seen like this shows an example of input, and the desired output *from that input*.

Comment: O sorry, but i try to found but the problem was i was not setting exact date formate

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert string to date in objective-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380381/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Tue, 25 May 2010 12:53:58 +0000";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, d LLLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

But First

1. Create a `NSDateFormatter` to convert the date string to a `NSDate`
   object.
2. Create a second `NSDateFormatter` (or change the format string of the
   first) to convert the `NSDate` back to a string.

Will this be a bit helpful ???

**EDIT**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2011-04-0600:28:27"];
```

Comment: How can  mention time zone for resulting date format, Like i want date for California time zone.

Answer (score 13):

Use this method. Pass your string into it & set Date format as desired. You will get your desired date in return.

```
- (NSDate *) getDateFromString:(NSString *) inputDate
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateForm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateForm setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDate *dateSelected = [dateForm dateFromString:inputDate];

    [dateForm release];

    return dateSelected;
}
```

Hope it works for you.

===============================================================

Date Format Options are as follows:

Now you want all the string formats that can be used with NSDateFormatter. Here is that

a: AM/PM

A: 0~86399999 (Millisecond of Day)

c/cc: 1~7 (Day of Week)

ccc: Sun/Mon/Tue/Wed/Thu/Fri/Sat

cccc: Sunday/Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday/Thursday/Friday/Saturday

d: 1~31 (0 padded Day of Month)

D: 1~366 (0 padded Day of Year)

e: 1~7 (0 padded Day of Week)

E~EEE: Sun/Mon/Tue/Wed/Thu/Fri/Sat

EEEE: Sunday/Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday/Thursday/Friday/Saturday

F: 1~5 (0 padded Week of Month, first day of week = Monday)

g: Julian Day Number (number of days since 4713 BC January 1)

G~GGG: BC/AD (Era Designator Abbreviated)

GGGG: Before Christ/Anno Domini

h: 1~12 (0 padded Hour (12hr))

H: 0~23 (0 padded Hour (24hr))

k: 1~24 (0 padded Hour (24hr)

K: 0~11 (0 padded Hour (12hr))

L/LL: 1~12 (0 padded Month)

LLL: Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec

LLLL: January/February/March/April/May/June/July/August/September/October/November/December

m: 0~59 (0 padded Minute)

M/MM: 1~12 (0 padded Month)

MMM: Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec

MMMM: January/February/March/April/May/June/July/August/September/October/November/December

q/qq: 1~4 (0 padded Quarter)

qqq: Q1/Q2/Q3/Q4

qqqq: 1st quarter/2nd quarter/3rd quarter/4th quarter

Q/QQ: 1~4 (0 padded Quarter)

QQQ: Q1/Q2/Q3/Q4

QQQQ: 1st quarter/2nd quarter/3rd quarter/4th quarter

s: 0~59 (0 padded Second)

S: (rounded Sub-Second)

u: (0 padded Year)

v~vvv: (General GMT Timezone Abbreviation)

vvvv: (General GMT Timezone Name)

w: 1~53 (0 padded Week of Year, 1st day of week = Sunday, NB: 1st week of year starts from the last Sunday of last year)

W: 1~5 (0 padded Week of Month, 1st day of week = Sunday)

y/yyyy: (Full Year)

yy/yyy: (2 Digits Year)

Y/YYYY: (Full Year, starting from the Sunday of the 1st week of year)

YY/YYY: (2 Digits Year, starting from the Sunday of the 1st week of year)

z~zzz: (Specific GMT Timezone Abbreviation)

zzzz: (Specific GMT Timezone Name)

Z: +0000 (RFC 822 Timezone)

==========================================

Set the format as you like..

Comment: @this is awesome . Is there a way to get the date like Saturday 30th, Jan 2016

Answer (score 2):

Use this bellow method with pass your Date...

```
       -(NSString *)StringFromDate:(NSString *)DateLocal{
        DateLocal = [self trimString:DateLocal];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];   
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd LLL yyyy hh:mm:ss Z"];

        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: DateLocal];
        NSString *tt = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
        NSDate *dateReturn = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tt];


        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE LLL dd yyyy hh:mm a"];
        NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateReturn];  
        NSLog(@"Date is HERE  =====>> %@",dateString);
        [dateFormat release];
        return dateString;
    }
```