# converting date to correct format

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've a webservice which gives back my date in the following way.

```
Wed Oct 31 11:59:44 +0000 2012
```

But I want it to give it back in this way

```
31-10-2012 11:59
```

I know that it should be done with a NSDateFormatter. But I don't now how to implement it in the correct way.

I've something like this.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0:00"]];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[genkInfo objectForKey:DATE]];
```

Can anybody help me?

Kind regards.

**Code at the moment**

```
  NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setDateFormat:@"E MMM d hh:mm:ss Z y"];
    NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:@"Wed Oct 31 11:59:44 +0000 2012"];
    NSDateFormatter *f2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [f2 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-y hh:mm"];
    [f2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSString *date2 = [f2 stringFromDate:date];
```

**Webservice layout**

```
"text": "KRC Genk | Zaterdag is er opnieuw een open stadiontour http://t.co/tSbZ2fYG",
"created_at": "Fri Nov 02 12:49:34 +0000 2012"
```

Comment: Hope it resolves your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13024673/1111384

Comment: weird. it's the same code. try and clean ur project and run it again

Comment: @RamyKfoury Thank you for your help in advance, but cleaned my project   and runned again, but still without success. I will edit my question of how my webservice looks like.

Comment: Are u sure ur reading the server string right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: create an NSDateFormatter to convert your string from server to an NSDate object by setting the format to the format of the "server string"

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"E MMM d hh:mm:ss Z y"];
NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:@"Wed Oct 31 11:59:44 +0000 2012"];
```

Step 2: create another NSDateFormatter with the desired output string and convert your new   NSDate object to a string object using the new NSDateFormatter

```
NSDateFormatter *f2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f2 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-y hh:mm"];
[f2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSString *s = [f2 stringFromDate:date];

desiredformat = s;
```

P.S. I'm not sure of f format, check this link 
http://www.developers-life.com/nsdateformatter-and-uifont.html

Comment: Changed that but still giving null.

Comment: Thank you for your help but still getting null, I edited my code of how it looks at the moment.

Comment: @StefGeelen I'm running your updated code, and it works, except you need to specify a timeZone on the second formatter, or your dates will differ.

Comment: Strange, because I copied and passed your code but still not working. Any idea what the problem can be?

Comment: I've edited my code again. I think this is exactly looks the same as your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your format string for parsing the original date. And the locale isn't set properly. There is no need to set the timezone. That will be processed from the supplied date/time string.

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *posix = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[f setLocale:posix];
[f setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:@"Wed Oct 31 11:59:44 +0000 2012"];
```

You want to use the en_US_POSIX locale whenever you are parsing (or formatting) a fixed format date that is not from or for a user. Do not use the en_US_POSIX locale to display dates or times to a user.