# iOS NSDateFormatter Format Date And Year In Number While Day In Words

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a simple app in which i am parsing date from and rss feed and showing it in the tableview. The default date string gives the following output:

> Sun, 18 Nov 2012 09:21:46 +0000

While i want it to give the output as follow:

> Sun, 18 Nov 2012

and skip the rest of the part which contains time.

This is what i have done but it returns nothing.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM d, ''yy"];


NSDate *receivedDate = [df dateFromString:currentString];
[self setPubTime:[df stringFromDate:receivedDate]];
```

Comment: Perhaps read the spec?  And follow the breadcrumbs to the [format pattern](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) doc?

Comment: (And may be use `stringFromDate`?)

Comment: You need two date formats. One to convert the date string in the RSS feed to an `NSDate`. Then you need the 2nd to convert the `NSDate` to the new format (as an `NSString`) that you want.

Comment: @AJ112 Did you read my comment? You need two data formatters.

Comment: @rmaddy can you show how in the answer?

Comment: You first need to tell us what format the date string is in the RSS feed. Also, there are plenty of existing questions that show you how to convert a date string from one format to another. Do some searching.

Comment: think you need to follow rmaddy's comment.  you need date formatter to be configured with the date format in the origin string, then read that string into a nsdate object, then change your date formatter to the desired format and output your string from your nsdate.

Comment: samo, samo...  Titles are different.  But a similar topic appears every several seconds.  Where do these date format topics come from?

Comment: Since you aren't really changing the format just removing the time, have you considered keeping it as a string NSString *value = [currentString substringToIndex:([currentString length] - 15)]; If your date format form the source is constant, this should work

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting date to correct format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196353/converting-date-to-correct-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df1 setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSDate *newDate = [df1 dateFromString:currentSring];
NSDateFormatter *df2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df2 setDateFormat:@"EEE,d MMM yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:newDate];
NSLog(@"date is %@",dateString);
NSDate *formattedDate = [df2 dateFromString:dateString];
```

Now if you want to get the date as string, simply remove the last statement. Keep in mind that you cannot check the format of date by NSLog if it is a date variable. It will only print in GMT format. To check it you need to convert date to string as done above.

Now if there is no zero paddind in date, you have to give 'dd' instead of 'd' and if time is 24hr format give 'HH' instead of 'hh'. Note that the format of df1 should be set as exactly the same of your 'currentString' including any spaces, etc.