# convert string to NSDate with custom format

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSString to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate)
>   [iPhone: How to convert “yyyyMMddThhmmss” format string to NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538658/iphone-how-to-convert-yyyymmddthhmmss-format-string-to-nsdate)

How do I convert this format to NSDate ?

My string date format is: `yyyy-m-d'T'H:m:ss` (no space between intervals).

Update:

```
2012-11-06T12:17:22.947 would be the string that I'd like to convert to NSDate
```

Comment: @Jennis: I'm don't think so, check my updates to the question.

Comment: @el.severo try my bellow method with new format ..

Comment: Well selected answer in that question contains documentation link and also unicode format string. May be you could have easily figured from that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13024673/1111384 Check this out. I Hope it'll work for you.

Comment: @el.severo i think edit your string format .. bcoz its not right and see your example date so i think the format is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just paste this method in your .m file and then call this method with your stringDate..

```
-(NSDate *)convertStringToDate:(NSString *) date {

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDate *nowDate = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
date = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+0000" withString:@""];
nowDate = [formatter dateFromString:date];
// NSLog(@"date============================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : %@", nowDate);
return nowDate;

}
```