# Change Date Format to special format in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, parsing, date

I used AFFeedParser in my app for parsing the article from different HTML page.

By parsing, I got the written `article DATE like`

`"Thu, 06 Dec 2012 17:44:22 +0000\n\t\t"` as a string.

How can I convert this into Date like `Thursday,December 06,2012`?

Comment: google or in SO, thousands of answer similar to this is there.. or check NSDate documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: you can check my answer no compatible with ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Log also, i got it...

```
    NSString *yourStringDate = @"Thu, 06 Dec 2012 17:44:22 +0000\n\t\t";
    NSString *str =[yourStringDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

    str =[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
    [str retain];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: str];

    dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE,LLLL dd,yyyy"];

    NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
```

**OUTPUT IS : Converted String : Thursday,December 06,2012**

Also see my Another answer for get NSDate from string but in that you just set your format like above , just change the format from that... [convert-string-to-nsdate-with-custom-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251633/convert-string-to-nsdate-with-custom-format/13251656#13251656)

i hope this helpful to you....

Comment: i am getting null as converted string

Comment: @user1673099 see this give the right output, just copy and paste this code in your method or in viewWillAppear also... :) i edit whole code dude... copy now and use it...

Comment: yes,you are right, it's because of \n\t\t, it is not working properly

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *dateStr=@"Thu, 06 Dec 2012 17:44:22 +0000\n\t\t";
NSString *getDate=[[dateStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\"]objectAtIndex:0];
```

**Here, you should take care of local representation of date and time so you should use.**

```
NSDateFormatter dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"yMMMMd" options:0 locale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];

NSDate *date=[dateFormat dateFromString:getDate];

NSLog(@"dateString = %@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the answer:

```
NSString *inputDate=@"Thu, 06 Dec 2012 17:44:22 +0000\n\t\t";
NSString *trimDate=[[inputDate componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"]objectAtIndex:0];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:trimDate];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM dd,yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"dateString = %@", dateString);
```

Output:

```
dateString = Thursday,December 06,2012
```

Comment: Explanation of line 2: He creates an `NSArray` separated by "\" which returns "Thu, 06 Dec 2012 17:44:22 +0000","n","t","t" and selects the first element.

Comment: no.... @"\" cant be used, so @"\\" one extra \ is used as escape character.  Then Thu, `06 Dec 2012 17:44:22 +0000` is stored in the first index (i.e. 0) in the array that is stored in trimDate...after that it is simple.

Comment: As you see I translated @"\\" to the human "\" which is easier to understand, because not everybody knows what stringescaping means. Second, I tried to create a pseudo-array which contains 4 elements: 1:"Thu, 06 Dec 2012 17:44:22 +0000" | 2: "n" | 3: "t" | 4: "t". (I'm sorry that the "+0000" got on the next line in my first comment.)

Comment: @FabioPoloni : Exactly, this is the logic, but where  is the OP, he should also take care of our labor....   we think code, post for no result :)

Comment: Comments like these is why I love SO.

Comment: but dateWithNaturalLanguageString method is getting error. Is there any framework required??

Comment: @FabioPoloni: due to ios and mac API, i need to change the code, now this code will work on ios...

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: You don't have to separate by "+". Timezone (+0000) is supported by iOS.

Comment: no, actually dateWithNaturalLanguageString  is not in ios. So i have to again use formatter. And as you said @"\\" will create confusion, so why not to break the array be +. NO confusion to anyone :)