# How to convert facebook post/message time to normal NSDate

Tags: iphone, ios, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a simple way of converting an ISO8601 timestamp to a formatted NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201216/is-there-a-simple-way-of-converting-an-iso8601-timestamp-to-a-formatted-nsdate)
>   [How to convert string to date in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380381/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-objective-c)

If I do requestForGrpahPath:@"me/inbox" with read_mailbox permission then I get this:

```
"data": [
          {
            "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "from": {
              "name": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "message": "yeup!",
            "created_time": "2012-12-03T10:28:21+0000"   // how to convert this time to normal NSdate
          },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Date format in your case is,

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

You can check the other links I have mentioned in comments for more details.