# Validation for input string is Date or not?

Tags: ios, nsdate

I have a textfield where the user can enter their date of birth, now i wants to make sure whether the input is of date format before saving into database. I gone through the SO , but still i didn't get the answer. Can anyone tell me how to validate(is it date) the input.

**The date  format would be MM/DD/YYYY**

**Note:I don't want the user to select date through date picker.**

Comment: I think there is no easy way to do it. You have to separate the NSString into components separated by /. And than have to do indivdual validation on each compoent regarding their length and value.

Comment: I know date formatting , but the problem is the user may give values like "1122344"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *dateFromTextfield = @"07/24/2013";

   // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];// here set format which you want...
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateFromTextfield]; 
    [dateFormat release];
```

and then check

```
//set int position to 2 and 5  as it contain / for a valid date
unichar ch = [dateFromTextfield characterAtIndex:position];
NSLog(@"%c", ch);

if (ch == '/') 
{
 //valid date
}
else
 { 
 //not a valid date
}
```

Comment: I know this, lets assume the dateFromTextfield= @"123.456" how you check whether the dateFromTextfield is valid date or not

Comment: `if (date == nil) { NSLog(@"Date not valid"); }`

Comment: something like this NSString *validationconditiontobematch = @"[0-9/]{1,8})";

Comment: @surendher 1) if i give the input for dateFromTextfield as "07/". it will crash the App. 2) the user can also enter as input as other than number and / (like "Cr/sh/"). Please answer me.

Comment: Vijay sure for it it need to be add validate check previous comment of mine

Answer (score 1):

[Convert string to date in my iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380381/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-objective-c)

Then check if it is or isn't nil.  Maybe also check that it is within a reasonable bound for whatever your application is

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use `UIDatePicker` because it's designed special for this, it's a natural way to select a date on iOS platform. 
Anyway if you want to check if string from `UITextField` is a date, format (using a formatter) it and get date relying on formatter

```
NSString *dateAsString = @"2010-05-24" // string from textfield
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate * dateFromString = [myDateFormatter dateFromString:dateAsString];
```

If `NSDate` is not nil, then it's ok, else something is wrong: user typed not a date or date which user typed has a wrong format.

**TRY TO PROVIDE A HINT FOR USER, LIKE EXAMPLE: 'DATE SHOULD HAVE FORMAT: yyyy-dd-MM'**

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *dateFromTextfield = @"07/24/2013";

//Extra validation, because the user can enter UTC date as completely in textfield,
//Here i assumed that you would expect only string lenth of 10 for date
//If more than digits then invalid date.
if ([dateFromTextfield length]>10) {

    //Show alert invalid date

    return;

}

//If you give the correct date format then only date formatter will convert it to NSDate. Otherwise return nil.
//So we can make use of that to find out whether the user has entered date or not.

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateFromTextfield];
[dateFormat release];

//If date and date object is kind of NSDate class, then it must be a date produced by dateFormat.
if (date!=nil && [date isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {

    //User has entered date
    // '/' and numbers only entered

}
else{

    //Show alert invalid date

    //Other than that date format.
}
```