# How to validate the UITextField Text when the user enter the value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, date

In my app the user enters the time in the **UITextField**,

I have used the **NSDateFormatter** to set the time in according to the format **YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss**.

I want to to check/validate whether time entered in the UITextField so that the user enters the time in HH and mm.

How can I can set the **VALIDATION** on the **UITEXTFIELD** input?

Thanks

Comment: Use UIDatePicker for selection...After selected of date your can change the Date Format as per your need and apply it to text field..
This reduces the code of validation..& efficient way!

Comment: check this following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827702/validation-for-input-string-is-date-or-not

Comment: Thank you, done it through the NSDateFormatter

Answer (score 0):

The way you are taking input is not suitable. Time input can be taken by UIDatePicker.

```
-(IBAction)showDatePicker:(id)sender{

    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 325, 300)];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    datePicker.hidden = NO;
    datePicker.date = [NSDate date];

    [datePicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(LabelChange:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
  {


    NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateformatter stringFromDate:[datePicker date]]); //here you will get selected Date


 }
```

You can choose DatePickerMode by any of them according to your requirement.

```
UIDatePickerModeTime,
UIDatePickerModeDate,
UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
```

NOTE: You can also use NSDateFormatter, and validate If you donot want to use UIDatePicker. In second method you have to add it string instead of date from picker.