# Objective-C: how to get day and date from NSDate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Considering the example  from [Convert string to date in my iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380381/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-objective-c)

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Tue, 25 May 2010 12:53:58 +0000";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, d LLLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr]; 
[dateFormat release];
```

I checked what methods `NSDate` has and found
[image]

**Question**
How can I get `Tue` and `25` from `*date`?

Comment: Look at `NSDateComponents`.

Comment: ... and to make some obvious-with-hindsight points to aid your learning: `NSDate`s don't have a day in them. They represent an instant in time (and, yes, perhaps don't have the best name: think of them as `NSTimestamp` if it's easier). So you need to get a calendar in there somewhere to impute the concept of numbered days relative to some start date. The output should differ depending on Gregorian, Julian, Chinese, Buddhist, etc, calendars and does.

Comment: Off-topic: What is this documentation you're using, is it some sort of Xcode plugin?

Comment: Its AppCode. http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `NSDateComponents` for this:

```
NSCalendar * calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [calendar components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate: <yourDate>];

NSLog(@"Day in week: %ld", (long)dateComponents.weekday); // Day in week: 3
NSLog(@"Day in month: %ld", (long)dateComponents.day);    // Day in month: 25
NSLog(@"Day name: %@", calendar.shortWeekdaySymbols[dateComponents.weekday - 1]); // Day name: Tue (iOS 8.0 +)
```

---

*Or in Swift*

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let dateComponents = calendar.components(.DayCalendarUnit | .WeekdayCalendarUnit, fromDate: <yourDate>)

println("Day in week: \(dateComponents.weekday)") // Day in week: 3
println("Day in month: \(dateComponents.day)")    // Day in month: 25
println("Day name: \(calendar.shortWeekdaySymbols[dateComponents.weekday - 1])") // Day name: Tue
```

Comment: I get error `'shortWeekdaySymbols' is unavailable: not available on iOS 7.1`

Comment: `shortWeekdaySymbols` is a class method of `NSDateFormatter`, not `NSCalendar`.

Comment: It's an instance method on `NSCalendar` from iOS 8.0… see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/Foundation.html (and also an `NSDateFormatter` *instance* method prior to that)

Comment: Note that there's nothing wrong with just using NSDateFormatter.  It's slightly less efficient, but most iOS programmers get to be familiar with it, so it's likely to code up faster.

Comment: Maybe, but I'd suggest that any programmer taking more than a cursory glance at dates would familiar be with `NSDateComponents` (or should take this as a learning opportunity)

Comment: @AshleyMills Strange. The API diffs indicate the changes but the actual reference docs do not.